Why is my coleus so sad looking?
I just got her so she hasn’t been repotted yet, ive heard they can be dramatic but i don’t want to over water her

Isn't it dry now?

she was being really dramatic, she was just thirsty

Well it's clearly suffering from serious drought. If the pot it's growing in has drainage holes, then over watering is quite difficult to achieve, provided you don't leave the pot sitting in a tray or saucer full of water once it's been watered. Water when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, water thoroughly and empty any outer tray or saucer 30 minutes after watering.
Right now, it looks so dry you may have to water 2 or 3 times in a short space of time, leaving it in a tray or outer pot with the water that comes out of the pot for an hour or so to get the soil nice and damp again. Either that or plunge it, which involves finding a container (like a bucket) bigger than the pot, filling with water, putting the pot in and weighting it down so the pot,but not the whole plant, is submerged for 30 minutes to an hour, then removing it and allowing it to drain down freely. If it recovers, don't repot while it's dry, get it damp right through before potting on.
